# How can I use a value from a global array locally in a function in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, function, global-variables, local-variables

Thanks if you are reading this. My problem is that I can't access inside my array from a function. For example:

```
$users = ["admin" => "admin","Alejandro" => "8345245"];
$userName = "Alejandro"
$UserPass = "8345245";
function checkUser(){
if( $users[$userName] == $userPass){
    return "The password is good";
}
```

This is my problem, I know to use global variables in a function I can use GLOBALS but here in an array if I use $GLOBALS["users[$GLOBALS["userName"]"] it does not work well.
Thank you so much.

Comment: See; [The global keyword](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global). You can simply use `global $users;` at the beginning of your function.

Comment: Thank you @KIKOSoftware, but I do not understand it. Can you explain it with an example. Thanks.

Comment: If you use the quotes correctly https://3v4l.org/S6ujS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See; [The global keyword](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global).
You can simply use `global $users;` at the beginning of your function. Like this:

```
$users = ["admin" => "admin","Alejandro" => "8345245"];
$userName = "Alejandro"
$UserPass = "8345245";

function checkUser() 
{
    global $users,$userName,$UserPass;
    if( $users[$userName] == $userPass) {
        return "The password is good";
    }
}

echo checkUser();
```

But this would make more sense:

```
$users = ["admin" => "admin","Alejandro" => "8345245"];

function checkUser($userName,$UserPass) 
{
    global $users;
    if( $users[$userName] == $userPass) {
        return "The password is good";
    }
}

echo checkUser("Alejandro","8345245");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I already understand perfectly. I'm learning and I really appreciate people like you, thank you for explaining it so well. @KIKOSoftware